# How to create a Websocket SessionManager that are reachable from other classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, autowired

I am working on an application with a WebSocket and want to save the clients id and session to a manager but have difficulties to understand how to do this correct when I also want to be able to reach this from another class with autowire.

```
public class Client {

    private String id;
    private Session session;
    private MessageHandler handler;  

    Client(String id, Session session, MessageHandler handler) {
        this.id = id;
        this.session = session;
        this.handler = handler;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ClientsManager {

    private Set<Client> clientSet = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    public Set<Client> getClients() {
        return this.clientSet;
    } 

    public void addClient(Client client) {
        this.clientSet.add(client);
    }

    public void removeClient(Client client) {
        clientSet.remove(client);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class WebsocketServerEndpoint         {

    public static final ClientsManager manageClients = new ClientsManager();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("connectId") String connectId) throws IOException, EncodeException {

        MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
        Client client = new Client(connectId, session, messageHandler);
        this.client = client;
        manageClients.addClient(client);
    }
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....

}
```

From another class:

```
public class DoSomething       {

        @Autowired
        WebsocketServerEndpoint serverEndpoint;

        public String doSomething()  {
        int numberOfClients = serverEndpoint.getClients().size()
        return numberOfClients;
       }
}
```

As I understand. This is not correct and you should not autowire static fields and so.

I can see when I debug that serverEndpoint: null in my DoSomething class but I get 1 connected client if I have one connected and so on.
When I do like this I will get the right number of clients in DoSomething class.
Have I just misunderstood this and it works as I have done?
or how should I do instead?
Is their a better way to write my Client and ClientsManager classes?

What I have read that if I would like to "Autowire" anyway there is two possible ways.

1. Using Constructor @Autowired For Static Field
2. Using @PostConstruct to set the value to Static Field

But how does this work when I would like to instantiate   "public static final ClientsManager manageClients = new ClientsManager();"

Sorry for my stupid question but I feel I do not fully understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to understand more about this topic search for Spring Dependency injection, but I write a short summary. 
To be able to @Autowire a component you have to create a @Bean or @Service or @Component.

1. Creating beands first create a Configuration class, and a Beand or Beans inside.

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class Configuration {

          @Value("${configuration.property.name}")
          String username;

          @Bean
          public WebsocketServerEndpoint ebsocketServerEndpoint () {
             return new WebsocketServerEndpoint();
          }

   }
   ```

`@Value` is not necessaty just good to mention with this annotation you can get a property name from spring `application.properties` file.

After this point you have created a @Bean instance of your class it is registered as a singleton class. You can get this one copy class from anywhere in your application you just have to, autowire it.

Or user construcor based dependency injection. ( @Autowired is not prefered).

2. Dont create beans just add `@Component` annotation to your class that you want to `Autowire` but I show a constructor injection.

   ```
   @Component
   public class WebsocketServerEndpoint {
       public String test(){
           return "test";
       }
   }

   @RestController
   public class DoSomething {

       private final WebsocketServerEndpoint websocketHandler;

       public DoSomething(WebsocketServerEndpoint websocketHandler) {
           this.websocketHandler = websocketHandler;
       }

       @GetMapping(value = "/test")
       public String test() {
           return websocketHandler.test();
       }
   }
   ```

You can even test this endpoint with a curl GET request. `curl http://localhost:8080/test`